# Class resolution issue by Java.lang.reflect.Method in Maven Project

Tags: maven, dependencies, java

In our maven project, we are using two dependencies, one of the dependency(Lets call it dependency1)consists of multiple transitive dependencies, one of the transitive dependencies, one of the Classes(Lets call it classA) which is creating and invoking virtualMachine.attach() method using reflection.
The dependency2 has internally com.sun.tools.attach package.

Now when this classA is trying to create and invoke the VirtualMachine, it's picking the VirtualMachine class from the dependency2, instead of tools.jar of JDK, due to which we are facing some issue. Is there a way to make the dependency1 to use the virtualMachine class of JDK instead of dependency2.

Comment: There should be only one `VirtualMachine` class, provided by the runtime, regardless of what dependencies you have specified to Maven. When there is a different `VirtualMachine` class, where does it come from?

Comment: @Holger  It's part of this depedency, which we are using in our project
<groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
<artifactId>powermock-module-javaagent</artifactId>
<version>1.7.4</version>

Comment: Including an attach API implementation ripped off from a particular Java implementation and running it in arbitrary others is a recipe to get arbitrary compatibility problems, up to crashing the entire virtual machine. There is no point in doing so. Either, the current environment has an implementation, then use it, or it is not guaranteed that the implementation of a different environment will work.

Comment: Actually, the VirtualMachine is used by some other dependency which we don't have control over, so is there a way to make that dependency to use VirtualMachine class from tools.jar of JDK rather than powermock

Comment: I’m not ruse whether you read my last comment correctly. Just answer one question. Why is it a problem that “some other dependency” uses the `VirtualMachine` class from powermock rather than the runtime’s tools.jar?

Comment: Actually Virtual Machine is internally using AttachProvider class, again the same case using AttachProvider of powermock instead of tools.jar, the logic in both the attachproviders isn't same, due to that facing issue while running.

Comment: That’s very fuzzy, “isn't same”, “facing issue”… Is it just like I said in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69525952/?noredirect=1#comment122897406_69525952) that a copy of an Attach API stemming from a different environment may cause problems? So, even if powermock tried to use that version in the current environment, it would cause the same problems? In other words, the actual problem is that powermock ships with an inappropriate copy of the Attach API, instead of using the API provided by the runtime. Don’t try to run both at the same time, get rid of the wrong one.